# XML Preload File in Android

Tags: android, xml

I need to preload an XML file (that I created before), that I need to modify and edit later in my application. Where should I copy this file, in wich folder? Should I copy later into a /sdcard/ folder?

How can I copy it when the program is started for the first time? only for this first time.

Need to mention that I'm going to need the path of the folder for open this XML file or modify it.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no other application will going to use this File later on than use Application's Internal storage,

[getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) which will give you File System path on your application files are placed internally.

Else you can use [getExternalStorageDirectory ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) which will give you sdcard path.

> How can I copy it when the program is started for the first time? only
>   for this first time

store preference of first time application open in [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and use this for next time to check weather file is already available or not.

Comment: But where should I copy it to use after the Application's Internal Storage. In wich folder?

Comment: That has been said already. In the path delivered by getFilesDir(); At development put the file in assets dir. Then copy from assets to internal files dir. You do not need shared preferences to remenber that you copied the file as you first can check if the file is already copied.